# Как скрыть окно при запуске скрипта на powershell?

Tags: powershell

Есть скрипт на powershell, хотим добавить его в политику для каждого пользователя компании. Но нужно чтобы он выполнялся как скрытый процесс. Можно ли как то скрыть окно при запуске? Или может быть есть какие-либо другие варианты?

Answer (score 2):

```
PowerShell[.exe]
   [-WindowStyle <style>]
```

Задает стиль окна для сеанса. Допустимые значения: Normal, Minimized, Maximized и Hidden.

подробнее [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help) и тут[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629472.aspx)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, получается мы задаем стиль окно в самом ps скрипте? или указываем при запуске?

Comment: если указать при запуске, то запускаемое ПО будет скирыта. если внутри скрипта запускаете другое ПО, то также нужно указать параметры окна.

Comment: Смотрите, у меня есть скрипт, который в определенный момент времени перемещает некоторые файлы. Чтобы скрыть окно я пишу в коде самого start-process PowerShell.exe -arg $pwd\screen.ps1 -WindowStyle Hidden, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: `start-process PowerShell.exe  $pwd\screen.ps1  -ArgumentList  $arguments` , где `$arguments` содержит `-WindowStyle`.

Comment: Я очень извиняюсь, никогда ранее не сталкивался с ps. Мой вариант? PowerShell.exe $pwd\screen.ps1 -ArgumentList -WindowStyle Hidden

Comment: каждый запуск нового процесса должен содердать нужные тебе ключи. если ты внутри скрипта это делаешь, то нужно внутри скрипта указывать клчи. `start-process PowerShell.exe $pwd\screen.ps1 -ArgumentList $arguments`

Answer (score 0):

Запуск ps1 из Планировщика заданий или ярлыка Windows скрытно.

```
mshta vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").Run ""powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass & 'C:\PATH\NAME.ps1'"", 0:close")
```